# Como fazer um daemon para o comando "mongod"

Tags: mongodb

Qual é o procedimento para deixar o Mongo rodando no servidor sem a necessidade de usar o comando `mongod`?

Existe algum comando especifico do Mongo para isto?

Comment: Provavelmente você pode instalar ele como serviço e rodá-lo. Uma curiosidade: você está usando linux?

Comment: Sim, linux no servidor.

Comment: Você precisa criar um usuário com nome sugestivo e programar o linux para que este programa rode naquele usuário sempre que o pc reiniciar.

Comment: Não precisa de nada disso, olha minha resposta. O próprio manual do Mongo tem a solução

Comment: Sem problemas Wallace Maxters. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se tiver usando o Linux, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
nohub mongod &
```

O Nohup fará com que o processo continue rodando em background, mesmo que você deslogue do servidor (se você estiver usando o SSH).

Existe também uma possibilidade de você configurar um serviço para rodar esse comando:

Veja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233529/run-bash-script-as-daemon

## Atualização

De acordo com o [Manual do MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#StartingandStoppingMongo-RunningasaDaemon), a forma correta de fazer é usando o argumento `--fork` ao rodar o comando.

> To run a mongod process as a daemon (i.e. fork), and write its output to a log file, use the --fork and --logpath options. You must create the log directory; however, mongod will create the log file if it does not exist.

Tradução meia-boca:

> Para executar um processo mongod como um daemon, e escreva sua saída para um arquivo de log, use as opções `-=-fork` e `--logpath`. Você deve criar o diretório de log. No entanto, `mongod` irá criar o arquivo de log se ele não existe.

Para inicial o Daemon do mongo faça:

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
```

Para finalizar faça:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. Funcionou com mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log.

Comment: O Log é importante. Como você não vai estar acompanhando a saída do comando em realtime, você pode acompanhar erros ou qualquer outro evento ocorrido no Log.

Answer (score 2):

Depende você tá rodando no linux ou no windows?

Se for no Windows só fazer um bat ou fazer ele virar um serviço e colocar pra iniciar junto com o Windows se for no linux ai depende de qual distro você está usando. Vou deixar alguns links no comentário apenas para referência.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016880/run-mongodb-server-as-a-service-detached-from-terminal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/563970/how-can-i-install-mongodb-as-a-service-in-centos

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61503/how-to-start-mongodb-server-on-system-start

Comment: Essas referências ficam boas na resposta.

Comment: O mais correto, ao invés de fazer um BAT é usar o agendador de tarefas e criar uma nova tarefa que execute esta aplicação sempre que o Windows inicializar, não sendo necessário que o usuário faça login.